# Easy admin list modification

Tags: symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

I don't get this guys!

At this moment I still have only one entity (User). I manage my users with the FOSUserBundle.

I want to modify the fields displayed in my list. Like this right?

config.yml

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        Users:
            class: AppBundle\Entity\User
            list:
                fields:
                    - username
                    - email
                    - last_login
```

But I get this error when trying to do it;

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Warning: mb_strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, object
>   given") in @EasyAdmin/default/field_text.html.twig at line 4.

I've added a __toString() method in my User entity but it still doesn't work;

User.php

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getUsername();
}
```

I am pretty new to the whole Symfony thing, so can somebody please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed and will probably be available with the next stable release.

In the meantime you can fix this by manually copy paste this 5 lines into `EasyAdminTwigExtention.php` at line 269.

```
try {
     $value = (string) $value;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
         $value = '';
    }
```

Look [here](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/issues/539#issuecomment-187732875) for the same question I asked on Git. And [here](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/commit/d80005104f9027594ff6a20964ab31b9c0f13a4c#diff-0c199003d2370f3ea2800f894b951396R273) where the code is modified.